# 'EntityFramework' assembly error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Last night my pc turn off without a clean shutdown and this morning I am getting the following error trying to access my asp.net mvc 4 application:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. 
Parâmetro incorreto. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

I am looking for awnsers, I tried to remove all data from temp dir, clean solution and rebuild, changed the app pool and nothing

I need some advice please...

Comment: Did you try to install it again?

Comment: Just did it. It is working. But new assemblies are missing. Now it is complaining about Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth'... I am not using Oauth. I have removed all the references in my project. Is there anywhere else I want to set not to use Oauth?

Comment: I have removed Oauth using the package-manager, and now when cleaning/rebuilding solution I don´t get any Oauth files in my bin page. But the error still appers. This is the stack-trace:  [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth' or one of its dependencies. Parâmetro incorreto. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution removing all entity packages found by Visual Studio and reinstalling them  again. All process was accomplished using the package manager in TOOLS -> PACKAGE MANAGER